# Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll not returning definite collisions when the Layer is specified

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I specify the `LayerMask` on `Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll` then it's returning an empty list.

Obviously the first thing I tested was removing the `LayerMask` parameter and checking again... and it *did* return the objects in the radius in that case. So then I triple checked the layer of the `GameObject` and it 100% has the same value that I was passing to `Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll`. What other reasons could there be for no results coming back when the `LayerMask` is specified?

I've tried:

```
var hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, 50, EnemyLayerMask);
var hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, 50, 8);
var hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, 50, 0);
```

All return no matches.

Comment: Show how you are making the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified  the  code does work. It appears you're using an incorrect layer mask.  There are 3 ways to declare a LayerMask correctly:

1. Use a serialized field for the layer (Then in the inspector drop down select the correct layer or Layers - holding down control):

   [SerializeField] LayerMask EnemyLayerMask
2. Use  LayerMask.NameToLayer() method:

   EnemyLayerMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy"); //Assumes you have a layer named 'Enemy'
3. Use a lower level approach:

   EnemyLayerMask = 1 << 12; // Assumes your Enemy layer is layer #12

Full code I used to verify:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class VerifyingCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform AttackPoint;
    [SerializeField] float overlapRadius = 12f;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask EnemyLayerMask; //Method 1

    void Start()
    {
        //Method 2
        EnemyLayerMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("NonEnemy");

        //Method 3
        EnemyLayerMask = 1 << 12;

        var hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, 50f, EnemyLayerMask);

        print($"# of hit enemies? {hitEnemies.Length}");

        foreach(var enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            print(enemy.name);
        }
    }
}
```